# Regex to match first occurence of a string starting and ending with predefined characters

Tags: regex, invoice2data

I'm trying to match the first occurence for the company name: `EuroPayment Services S.R.L`. I tried to make it non-greedy by adding `?` but without success. What am I doing wrong?

```
  Name:          EuroPayment Services S.R.L.
  Address:         Str. Ion Cămpineanu, nr. 11, Bloc Union, etaj 8, camera 803
  Name:          General Motors S.R.L.
  Address:         Str. Ion Cămpineanu, nr. 11, Bloc Union, etaj 8, camera 803
```

Also, how can I match the second occurence of the company name? `General Motors S.R.L`

[Demo](http://regexr.com/652v7)

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? If you want to return _only_ the first occurrence, then don't use the `g` flag. What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Acc. to the docs, invoice2data uses Python `re`. That means you should not use regexr.com as your testing site, it does not support `re` flavor. Use regex101.com instead.

Comment: I'm using a tool named invoice2data to extract values from a pdf invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to capture the first name:

```
Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*
```

Sample run [here](https://regex101.com/r/HjJ4Q2/2).

You can also capture the nth-name through this (just update the 0-based index part `{n}` to your target e.g. `{4}` to get the 5th name:

- name 1: `(?:Name:[\s\S]+?){0}Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*`
- name 2: `(?:Name:[\s\S]+?){1}Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*`
- name 3: `(?:Name:[\s\S]+?){2}Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*`
- name 4: `(?:Name:[\s\S]+?){3}Name:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*`
- and so on...

Comment: Thanks but I only want the first occurrence: `Europayment Services SRL`

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you check if it fits your requirement?

Comment: thanks, it worked! do you know how can I capture the second match, too?

Comment: I updated my answer to capture any nth-name you would need whether 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 100th, etc. Can you try? Just update the index part e.g. to get the 5th item `{4}`.